# MySQL AVG() return 0 if NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, null, average

I have 3 tables, shown below:

```
mysql> select * from Raccoon;
+----+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | name             | image_url                                                                                          |
+----+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  3 | Jesse Coon James | http://www.pawfun.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/rabbid.png                                     |
|  4 | Bobby Coon       | https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5242/5370143072_dee60d0ce2_n.jpg                                     |
|  5 | Doc Raccoon      | http://images.encyclopedia.com/utility/image.aspx?id=2801690&imagetype=Manual&height=300&width=300 |
|  6 | Eddie the Rac    | http://www.felid.org/jpg/EDDIE%20THE%20RACCOON.jpg                                                 |
+----+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from Review;
+----+------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------+--------+
| id | raccoon_id | reviewer_id | review                                      | rating |
+----+------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------+--------+
|  1 |          3 |           1 | This raccoon was a fine raccoon indeed.     |      5 |
|  2 |          5 |           2 | This raccoon did not do much for me at all. |      2 |
|  3 |          3 |           1 | asdfsadfsadf                                |      5 |
|  4 |          5 |           2 | asdfsadf                                    |      1 |
+----+------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from Reviewer;
+----+---------------+
| id | reviewer_name |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | Kane Charles  |
|  2 | Cameron Foale |
+----+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm trying to build a select query that will return all of the columns in `Raccoon` as well as an extra column which grabs an average of `Review.rating` (grouped by id). The problem I face is that there is no guarantee that there will be rows present in the `Review` table for every single Raccoon (as determined by the FK, `raccoon_id` which references `Raccoon.id`. In situations where there are zero rows present in the `Review` table (for a given Raccoon.id, ie Review.raccoon_id) I'd like the query to return `0` as the average for that Raccoon.

Below is the current query I'm using:

```
mysql> SELECT *, (SELECT IFNULL(AVG(rating),0) FROM Review WHERE raccoon_id=Raccoon.id GROUP BY raccoon_id) AS "AVG" FROM Raccoon ORDER BY "AVG" ASC;
+----+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| id | name             | image_url                                                                                          | AVG    |
+----+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|  3 | Jesse Coon James | http://www.pawfun.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/rabbid.png                                     | 5.0000 |
|  4 | Bobby Coon       | https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5242/5370143072_dee60d0ce2_n.jpg                                     |   NULL |
|  5 | Doc Raccoon      | http://images.encyclopedia.com/utility/image.aspx?id=2801690&imagetype=Manual&height=300&width=300 | 1.5000 |
|  6 | Eddie the Rac    | http://www.felid.org/jpg/EDDIE%20THE%20RACCOON.jpg                                                 |   NULL |
+----+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see above, the query isn't returning `0` for Raccoons with id of 4 and 6, it is simply returning `NULL`. I need it to return something like the following (note the ordering, sorted by lowest average review first):

```
+----+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| id | name             | image_url                                                                                          | AVG    |
+----+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|  4 | Bobby Coon       | https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5242/5370143072_dee60d0ce2_n.jpg                                     | 0.0000 |
|  6 | Eddie the Rac    | http://www.felid.org/jpg/EDDIE%20THE%20RACCOON.jpg                                                 | 0.0000 |
|  5 | Doc Raccoon      | http://images.encyclopedia.com/utility/image.aspx?id=2801690&imagetype=Manual&height=300&width=300 | 1.5000 |
|  3 | Jesse Coon James | http://www.pawfun.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/rabbid.png                                     | 5.0000 |
+----+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `IFNULL` outside your subquery since it will return null it there is not match on the outer table,

```
IFNULL((SELECT AVG(rating) FROM Review WHERE raccoon_id=Raccoon.id GROUP BY raccoon_id), 0) AS "AVG"
```

Or you can also use `LEFT JOIN`,

```
SELECT  ra.id, ra.name, ra.image_url,
        IFNULL(AVG(rv.rating),0)AS "AVG" 
FROM    Raccoon ra
        LEFT JOIN Review rv
            ON rv.raccoon_id = ra.id
GROUP   BY ra.id, ra.name, ra.image_url  
ORDER   BY "AVG" ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want a `group by` in the subquery.  This is dangerous because it could return more than one row (although the `where` prevents this).  More importantly, with no `group by`, the subquery is an aggregation query that always returns one row.  So, you can put the logic in the subquery:

```
SELECT r.*,
       (SELECT COALESCE(AVG(rev.rating),0)
        FROM Review rev
        WHERE rev.raccoon_id = r.id
       ) AS "AVG"
FROM Raccoon r
ORDER BY "AVG" ASC;
```

Also:  always use qualified column names when you have a correlated subquery.  This is a good practice to prevent problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following SQL statement with the built-in function COALESCE():

```
SELECT *,  COALESCE((SELECT AVG(rating) FROM Review WHERE raccoon_id=Raccoon.id GROUP BY raccoon_id), 0) AS "AVG" FROM Raccoon ORDER BY "AVG" ASC;
```

You can find the manual of this function [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) .

If you prefer to use IFNULL, you can use

```
SELECT *, IFNULL((SELECT AVG(rating) FROM Review WHERE raccoon_id=Raccoon.id GROUP BY raccoon_id), 0) AS "AVG" FROM Raccoon ORDER BY "AVG" ASC;
```

Looks like you misunderstood the scope of the functions.

However, I think a better way is to use left outer join, instead of a sub query, here is the query I wrote for your reference:

```
select Raccoon.id, Raccoon.name, Raccoon.image_url, IFNULL(AVG(rating),0) avg from Raccoon LEFT OUTER join Review ON raccoon_id =Raccoon.id GROUP BY raccoon.id ORDER BY AVG ASC;
```

Then you will get the following results:
[image]

(sorry I don't know how I can post the output of this query, then I took a screenshot :-)

Hope this will help.